# Getting date difference in javascript

Tags: javascript, datediff

I know this is easy, but I cannot seem to figure this out.

I am looking for the difference in date between two dates in javascript.

```
var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("FromDate").value);  
var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById("ToDate").value);  

var date_diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()/86400000);
        if (date_diff > 90){
              alert('Selection criteria can not exceed 90 days.');
        }
```

My date_diff value is something unrealistic.
What is wrong with my code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var date_diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()/86400000);
```

should be

```
var date_diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/86400000;
```

Comment: Order of operations will get ya every time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You forget two braces. Try:

```
var date_diff = Math.abs((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/86400000);
```